# How to set the text of a TextView asynchronously?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have to fill a `ListView` with text info that takes time to gather.
My approach is to use AsyncTask to do the background job, but setting the text to the TextView when the result has arrived slows the list: the list lags every time `getView()` is called.

This is my `AsyncTask` class

```
private class BreadcrumbTask extends AsyncTask<FFile, Void, String>{
    private WeakReference<TextView> mTextView; 
    public BreadcrumbTask(TextView textView){
        mTextView = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(FFile... params) {
           // text processing
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (mTextView != null){
            TextView tv = mTextView.get();
            if (tv != null)
                //this line blocks the UI. if I comment it the lag is gone
                tv.setText(result); 
        }
```

//          mTextView.setText(result);
        }

I create a new task in getView() and I execute it.
The problem clearly comes from `tv.setText(result)` in `onPostExecute()`. When I comment the list flows nicely. So how can I update the `TextView` without slowing the UI?

Comment: check into how/where you're doing the AsyncTask .execute(), if in getView of your listView adapter, this could be getting called many times per view.  Perhaps some logging code in your getView and AsyncTask will help.  tv.setText() by itself certainly should muck things up on you.

Comment: @NathanZ Did you ever get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

**Hold View Objects in a View Holder**

Your code might call findViewById() frequently during the scrolling of ListView, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the "view holder" design pattern.

> A ViewHolder object stores each of the component views inside the tag
>   field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the
>   need to look them up repeatedly. First, you need to create a class to
>   hold your exact set of views. For example:

```
static class ViewHolder {
  TextView text;
  TextView timestamp;
  ImageView icon;
  ProgressBar progress;
  int position;
}
```

> Then populate the ViewHolder and store it inside the layout.

```
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_image);
holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_text);
holder.timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_timestamp);
holder.progress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

Some other examples :

[http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/)
http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

Answer (score 0):

You cann't update UI from another thread. But you can use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to update UI dynamically. Define a handler within your class and use it as follows:

**Declaration:**

```
String result = "";
Handler regularHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Update UI
   if(msg.what==3){
    if (mTextView != null){
            TextView tv = mTextView.get();
            if (tv != null){
                //this line blocks the UI. if I comment it the lag is gone
                tv.setText(result); 
            }
        }
     }
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Your code in onPostExecute**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //store the value in class variable result
                this.result = result;
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(3);
        }
```

Comment: I should not have to do that since onPostExecute() runs on the UI thread

Comment: Correct.  Not also that all Views have their own built-in handlers, so you could just have easily have done tv.post(new Runnable(){...});.  However, you're right that it's not needed in this case.

Comment: The use of WeakReference is very clever, but is it possible that this is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Edward might be on to something.  I did read the following note on the android developer site regarding weakreference for caching bitmaps.    Note: In the past, a popular memory cache implementation was a SoftReference or WeakReference bitmap cache, however this is not recommended. Starting from Android 2.3 (API Level 9) the garbage collector is more aggressive with collecting soft/weak references which makes them fairly ineffective. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

 if (mTextView != null){
        TextView tv = mTextView.get();
        if (tv != null)
            //this line blocks the UI. if I comment it the lag is gone
            tv.setText(result); 

}
```

Comment: `onPostExecute()` already executes on the UI thread. This does nothing.